# Holomorphic with a pole at 0

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that if $f : \mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ is holomorphic and $f(z) \rightarrow \infty$ as $z \rightarrow 0$ then $f$ has a pole at $0$.

So I know that for any $0 < r < R$, we have the Laurent series $f : D'(0, R) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $$f(z) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}c_nz^n \text{ where } c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma(0,r)}\frac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}\text{ dw}$$

I also know that there is a pole at $0$ iff $\exists \ n <0: c_n \neq 0$.

However, I don't know how to use the information that $f(z) \rightarrow \infty$ as $z \rightarrow 0$ to show that $f$ has a pole at $0$.

Comment: Look at the function $g=1/f$. Show that it is holomorphic and bounded in some punctured neighborhood of $0$. Conclude that it has a removable singularity at $z=0$ and therefore it has a zero there of some order. Therefore you can write $g(z)=z^nh(z)$ for some holomorphic $h$ with $h(0)\neq0$. It follows that $f(z)=z^{-n}/h(z)$.

Comment: @logarithm Is the following valid? Letting $g=1/f$ we see that for any $\epsilon$ we can find $\delta$ such that $|f(z)|>\epsilon^{-1}$ on $D'(0,\delta)$, so $g(z) \rightarrow 0$ as $z \rightarrow 0$ and hence $g$ can be extended to a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ with $g(z)=0$. Thus $f$ has a pole at 0.

Answer (score 0):

1. It should be clear that $f$ has no removable singularity at $0$.
2. Suppose that $f$ has an essential singularity at $0$. Then take any $w \in \mathbb C$. By Casorati- Weierstraß, there is a sequence $(z_n)$  in $ \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ such that $z_n \to 0$ and $f(z_n) \to w$. This contradicts $f(z) \to \infty$ as $z \to 0.$